# Automating Git CMD, is it possible?

Tags: git, command-line, cmd

I want to run a script from a batch file that will start up Git CMD. Is there anyway to automate cloning a git repository from the git cmd?

Comment: `git clone` does not need interactive input, and it should be enough to just run the command without any need to automate in any further.

Comment: Agree with gauteh.  Git is specifically designed so that console-commands are first-class citizens

Comment: what do you mean? When trying to clone the repository, i'm getting prompt to enter password, thats why i'm wondering if it can be automated so that the password can be entered as well as cloning.

Comment: Is the repository connected via HTTPS or via Git?  With HTTPS it's going to ask you for the password every time.

Comment: it's going to be connected username@git.urlname.com/filename.git

Comment: What does `git remote -v` tell you?

Comment: it is not a repository but it is.